# Trying to get sed to replace a filepath in a file with another filepath

Tags: bash, shell, sed

This is my current code. I am trying to replace a filename string in the file with another filename. But I am currently getting the error

> "sed: 1: "s/directory = "[A-Za-z0 ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'U'"

What is wrong with this code?

```
function restart_existing ()
{
    old="directory = \"[A-Za-z0-9\/]\""
    new="directory = \"$1\""
    sed -i '' "s/$old/$new/" "$HOME/angelpretendconfig" 
}


restart_existing "$HOME/blahblahblah/shoot/blah"
```

EDIT:
Thanks! I've adopted your advice, and adapted the code.

```
function restart_existing ()
{
    old="directory = \"*\""
    printf -v new 'directory = "%s"' "$1"
    sed -i '' "s;$old;$new;" "$HOME/angelpretendconfig" 
}

restart_existing "Query"
```

But now the line in question goes from

```
directory = "/home/jamie/bump/server"
directory = "Query"/home/jamie/bump/server"
```

Why does this occur?

Answer (score 7):

Don't use forward slashes in sed when what you're replacing *contains* forward slashes:

```
$ sed 's;foo/bar;baz/wuz;' <<< "where is the foo/bar?"
where is the baz/wuz?
```

Also, sometimes it's more readable to avoid manually escaping quotes:

```
function restart_existing ()
{
    old='directory = "[A-Za-z0-9\/]"'
    printf -v new 'directory = "%s"' "$1"
    sed -i '' "s;$old;$new;" "$HOME/angelpretendconfig" 
}

restart_existing "$HOME/blahblahblah/shoot/blah"
```

Comment: Thanks! I've adopted your advice, and adapted the code.


function restart_existing ()
{
    old="directory = \"*\""
    printf -v new 'directory = "%s"' "$1"
    sed -i '' "s;$old;$new;" "$HOME/angelpretendconfig" 
}

restart_existing "Query"

But now the line goes from

directory = "/home/jamie/bump/server"
directory = "Query"/home/jamie/bump/server"

Why does this occur?

Comment: @KennethTiong because `sed 's;directory = \"*\";something;'` means *Replace `directory =` followed by any number of double-quotes (plus one) with `something`*

Answer (score 1):

`$1` contains something, which is parsed as a special command to sed, in this case probably a `/` which marks the end of the replacement string, followed by some other characters.

You have to escape the replacement string first: [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-sed-search-pattern).